# Get datetime from database and split it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on a C# program. I created an EF code-first database in which I read in a csv file. This csv file contains a `DateTime` object. This `DateTime` object was saved in the database. Now I have to get this `DateTime` and parse it into the DATE (dd-mm-yyyy) and the TIME (hh:mm:ss.fff). Unfortunately I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
    private readonly PerformanceAnalyseToolContext db;

    public HomeController(PerformanceAnalyseToolContext db)
    {
       this.db = db;
    }

    public IActionResult ReadCsvData(string csvData) //get csvData String
    {
            ChartData chartData = new ChartData();
            string[] lines = csvData.Split("\n"); //Split after enter

            //List<ChartData> chartDataList = new List<ChartData>();

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(','); // SPlit after ,
                try //try catch, because if an error occurs the process has to continue
                {
                    chartData = new ChartData { //Create object from csv data
                        Timestamp = Convert.ToDateTime(values[0] + "." + values[1]),
                        Function = Convert.ToString(values[2]),
                        Duration = Convert.ToInt32(values[4]),
                        IsError = Convert.ToBoolean(values[5])
                    };

                    db.ChartDatas.Add(chartData); //Save object into database
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch(Exception exc)
                {
                    exc.ToString();
                }
            }

            return View(chartData);
        }

        public List<ChartDatanDTO> GetDataForChart(string function)
        { //here i get the Data from the DB
            return db.ChartDatas
                .Where(x => x.Function == function)
                .Select(x => new ChartDatanDTO
                {
                    durat = x.Duration,
                    err = x.IsError,
                    time =x.Timestamp
                })
                .ToList();
        }
```

Comment: You should consider using both answers, since both of them are valid information just for different tasks. Instead of using this `Convert.ToDateTime(values[0] + "." + values[1]);` you should consider using `AlkanV's` answer, since it will have the benefit to be culture independent - your current code will break with a different culture. And `ckal's` answer should be used to split the `DateTime` into string representation of `Date` and `Time`. So one answer is good to read from the CSV file the other is good to write to the CSV file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the format of your `DateTime` in the ToString method.

```
time = x.Timestamp.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff")
```

If you need them separated you can do ToString twice.

```
date = x.Timestamp.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
time = x.Timestamp.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff")
```

Comment: Thank you for that

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact()` method

`DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(yourDateTime, "yyyy/MM/DD",                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

for more info you can check:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime

Answer (score 0):

Convert function directly doesn't work in LINQ, 
So you also can use **[DBFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)**  to truncate time and  **[SqlFunctions.DatePart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** to get time

```
           ........

           .Select(x => new ChartDatanDTO
            {
                date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.YourDateTime),
                time = SqlFunctions.DatePart("hh", x.YourDateTime) + ":" + 
                SqlFunctions.DatePart("mm", x.YourDateTime) +":" + 
                SqlFunctions.DatePart("ss", x.YourDateTime)
            });
```